# Why getText() returns a number in Struts 2?

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, ognl

I'm upgrading an app from Struts 2.1 to Struts 2.3.23 but I have a strange error with the new version.

I have in my JSP the following code :

```
<span id="n1"><s:text name="%{getText('prod_n1')}"/></span>
```

And in my properties file :

```
prod_n1=N-1
```

For some reasons this gives me as output: `-1.0`.

**If I replace `N-1` by `foo`, then my output is `foo` as expected**. It looks like the `getText()` method see `N-1` as a number ! Any idea on how to fix it ?

Comment: `<s:text>` is for i18n.

Answer (score 0):

After more investigations, I can reproduce this bug on a blank page, it occurs only with the combinaison of calling getText inside a `<s:text/>` tag. In this configuration, the output is always a number if the input string begins or ends with a number and contains no spaces. It not only occurs with properties files but also with any input (such as session variables).

I took a look to Struts2 code and i think it's something with the way of extracting the text which leads to consider the input as a float.

So, just try not to use this method inside a "text" tag...

Answer (score 0):

The result of `getText('prod_n1')` will return `N - 1` as expected.

Then a result is used by the tag as OGNL that is parsed, and it's evaluated to `-1.0` if there's a key `N` in the `valueStack` that has a floating value `0`.

Then this key is used to find the value in the properties file. Since such key `-1.0` is not found the key is printed out.